# Pandas - Conditions on List as Datatype

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have this dataframe:

```
   SN  RESULT
 1 100 [A]
 2 101 [B]
 3 103 [A, B]
 4 104 [B]
```

The RESULT series is of datatype list. I want to be able to filter SN's that has *A* in it, so my output should be *100, 103*. I tried:

```
df["RESULT"] == ["A"]
```

and even:

```
df["RESULT"].isin(["A"])
```

as my condition but I only get an error since it thinks I'm trying to compare an entire series to a list.

> ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

I'm sure there's a way without taking the route of converting RESULTS series into string. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

#### comprehension

```
df[['A' in x for x in df.RESULT]]

    SN  RESULT
1  100     [A]
3  103  [A, B]
```

---

#### `set` logic

```
df[df.RESULT.map(set) >= {'A'}]

    SN  RESULT
1  100     [A]
3  103  [A, B]
```

---

#### `np.logical_or`

```
o = np.zeros(len(df), dtype=bool)
i = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(df.RESULT.str.len())
t = np.concatenate(df.RESULT.to_numpy()) == 'A'
np.logical_or.at(o, i, t)
df[o]

    SN  RESULT
1  100     [A]
3  103  [A, B]
```

Comment: Perfect, mapping is exactly what I wanted. It's just now that I thought about using it to come up with booleans. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Another one: `apply()` a str join and search via [`series.str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df[df.RESULT.apply(''.join).str.contains('A')]
```

Or without apply:

```
df[df.RESULT.str.join('').str.contains('A')] #thanks QuangHoang
```

---

```
    SN  RESULT
1  100     [A]
3  103  [A, B]
```

Comment: This does break if you're testing `'A' in ['B', 'CABBAGE']`

Comment: @piRSquared yes it does. :) looking at the op list looks like lists have a single char.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
df[pd.DataFrame(df.RESULT.tolist()).eq('A').any(1).values]
```